# How will we get local filesystem access in Jelastic Cloud PaaS

Tags: cloud, jelastic

I have successfully deployed spring MVC,JPA and MySql based application on Jelastic cloud, but i have an issue that i could not upload the lucence search indexes files and images(I am storing uploaded images on file system not in DB) on jelastic. So how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

For storing purposes you can use */home* directory of your app server's virtual container.
Files uploaded to this destination are stored regardless of deployment. You can perform your uploading through Jelastic UI ('config' button next to your app server icon in environment topology)
In case you need to set mentioned destination in your code, [this documentation](http://jelastic.com/docs/environment-variables) will be useful.

Much more info can be found on [Jelastic Community](http://community.jelastic.com/), so make sure you there))